# How to fix "ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':." Error in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I open any new project ,gradle shows me this error

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'customview.aar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'cursoradapter.aar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'customview.aar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'cursoradapter.aar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'customview.aar (androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'cursoradapter.aar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}.
>   Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOuWd.png)

Comment: Can you post your code/dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

go to build.gradle (Module:app) and replace implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+' with implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this , there was a problem in cache folder 
i deleted it and then generate new one

Answer (score 0):

In project build.gradle file update the classpath of gradle to latest version.